# What motivates the linear form of the Kalman Filter?

Tags: kalman-filter

The derivations of the Kalman Filter I've read express the state update estimate as $\hat{x}_t = F\hat{x}_{t-1} + K\tilde{y}$ (using Wikipedia notation). The derviations will go on to derive K by attempting to minimize the covariance of $\hat{x}_t$.

It's intuitive to me that a good estimate of $\hat{x}$ should be a function of $ F\hat{x}_{t-1}$ and $\tilde{y}$ , but what physical properties of the modeled system, theory, or practical implementation considerations motivate our designing an estimator that takes the linear combination of the two?

My thoughts so far: We want our estimator to output something gaussian that's in between $ F\hat{x}_{t-1}$ and $\tilde{y}$ with a small variance, and the form of the filter chosen is a very easy one to optimize. However, this doesn't seem to preclude the possibility that, if we chose a different form of equation to optimize, we may have gotten an even better result, as we only optimized for the value of K and not for the form of the equation itself. There's a lot more ways we could have chosen to combine our estimates.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that there is a great intuitive answer beyond saying that, for linear systems, the math shows that the optimal estimator is the form that the Kalman Filter takes. For linear systems, a different form of estimator won't be able to do any better.

For nonlinear systems, that's not true, and there may indeed be different forms of the solution. Extended Kalman Filters and Unscented Kalman Filters are used for nonlinear problems that are reasonably approximated as a linear system over short time steps, and so a similar linear update step is used. Particle filters are a much more general estimation method (but *way* more computationally expensive). Deciding the best estimate of a particle filter is a challenging problem, and usually is not a linear equation. For example, the estimate may be multi-modal, and so producing a single best estimate is poorly defined. If you are interested in that kind of thing, *Beyond the Kalman Filter: Particle Filters for Tracking Applications* is a good textbook introduction to particle filters, which assumes roughly graduate-level mathematics knowledge.